# Impossible to export static in django production

Tags: django, nginx, gunicorn

I'm trying to put in production a website using nginx and gunicorn but after a lot of attempt, my css and js are not visable.

The project root is /root/ouverture

My static files root is /root/ouverture/coloc/static

here it's what i have written in my settings.py

```
STATIC_ROOT  = "/static/" 
STATIC_URL = '/static/'
```

here is my /etc/nginx/sites-available/coloc

```
server {
    listen 80; server_name 51.91.111.135;
    root /root/ouverture/;
    location /static {
            root /root/ouverture/coloc/;
    }
    location / {
            proxy_set_header Host $http_host;
            proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-For $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;
            proxy_redirect off;
            proxy_pass http://127.0.0.1:8000;
    }
```

}

Can you help me please, I don't see where is my error. Thank you

Comment: try this article https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/how-to-set-up-django-with-postgres-nginx-and-gunicorn-on-ubuntu-16-04

Answer (score 0):

Why have you set `STATIC_ROOT  = "/static/"`? You want the static files to go into `/root/ouverture/coloc/static`, so that's what you should set STATIC_ROOT to. Then make sure you run collectstatic.

Answer (score 0):

There are something wrong with your configuration which you might want to take a look at that.

1. Your static files root. `My static files root is /root/ouverture/coloc/static` with this, your `STATIC_ROOT` supposed to be `STATIC_ROOT='/root/ouverture/coloc/static'` or maybe something like this `STATIC_ROOT=os.path.join(BASE_DIR, 'static')` and `BASE_DIR` is your project DIR (`BASE_DIR = os.path.dirname(os.path.dirname(os.path.dirname(__file__)))`)
2. You're trying to serve your application and also static files too so you might not need `root`, `alias` also works.

```
    location /static/ {
         alias /root/ouverture/coloc/static/;
    }
```

Just remember to run `./manage.py collectstatic` on your project so that your static files will be copied into `STATIC_ROOT` folder, check that your static files are there first, and then do it step by step until you can see any static files on `/static/` path.

Answer (score 0):

I have change my static_root to "/root/ouverture/coloc/static" and made the changes in the config files nginx. i've done the collectstatic too. but still the same problem, i only have the html but without css and js withtout any error..